# Serve jquery-ajax one by one

Tags: jquery

I have some tasks that I need them to be executed in order one by one:

```
function doTasks(tasks, urlDoTask) {
    // Create a deferred for each task by calling doTask().
    var deferreds = $(tasks).map(function (i, task) {
        return doTask(task, urlDoTask);
    }).toArray();

    // return a composite deferred which will wait for each of the doTask requests.
    return $.when.apply($, deferreds);
}

function doTask(task, urlDoTask) {

    return ajax({
        url: getRootDir() + urlDoTask,
        data: { param: task.SomeParam },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).then(function (data) {

        return ok(createObject("status", "ok", "op", "doTask", "task", task, "data", "passed"));
    },
        function (data) {

         return ok(createObject("status", "fail", "op", "doTask", "task", task, "data", "failed"));
        });
}

function ok() {
    return newPromise("resolve", arguments);
}

function newPromise(type, args) {
    return $.Deferred(function (dfd) {
        dfd[type].apply(dfd, args);
    }).promise();
}

function createObject() {
    var ob = {};

    // copy all the arguments name/value pairs into the object
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i += 2) {
        var n = arguments[i];
        var v = arguments[i + 1];

        ob[n] = v;
    }
    return ob;
}
```

How can I modify this code to make each doTask to be executed in order one by one? I have thought in using jquery queue but how to apply here? Maybe doing something like:

```
    var deferreds = $(tasks).map(function (i, task) {
        $({}).queue(doTask(task, urlDoTask));
    }).toArray();
```

and once each task has completed do next()?

Comment: @charlietfl I need data from each task to process into next task, for example, If I have task1, task2 and task3 what I want is to execute them in order, I mean, send jquery ajax calls in order, in this example, first send task1, when task1 completes, send task2, when task2 completes, send task3.

Comment: OK so you don't want array of deferreds then that you are getting useing `map`....you need to handle one deferred at a time...which is basically already there using `.done()` in `$.ajax` as others sugegst

Answer (score 1):

I prefer something that just seems a lot simpler.  Just start the next ajax call from the success handler of the previous one.

```
function processTasks(tasks, urlDoTask)

    var index = 0;
    function nextTask() {
        if (index < tasks.length) {
            $.ajax({
                url: getRootDir() + urlDoTask,
                data: { param: tasks[index].SomeParam },
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(result) {
                    // process ajax results here

                    // do next ajax call
                    ++index;
                    nextTask();
                }
            });
        }
    }
    // start first ajax call
    nextTask();
}
```

FYI, I'm assuming that `tasks` is an array of items from which you're getting `.SomeParam` for each successive ajax call.  If that's not the case, then please describe what `tasks` is.

Comment: I have just updated my post. I am trying to adapt my code to what you have stated but I am a little bit confused on how to adapt my above code in order to do the minimal modifications on it and to continue working. Note that doTasks function in my code waits for all tasks (ping requests) to be finished in order to continue and that doTask is returning some data on success or fail so could you guide me on how to adapt it to your code? I am very new in jquery/javascript programming...Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user304602 - I don't understand what you're trying to do with `createObject()` after each task completes.  Where are those objects getting stored?  Sorry, but your current code requires a very advanced understanding of promises in order to be understandable.  I was trying to make something much easier to understand.  It's easy enough to add that logic to do the `createObject()` on sucsess or fail of each task, but I don't understand what you want to do with them.  Perhaps you can describe in words what the desired data result is.

Answer (score 1):

my approach to these kinds of problem is to have the function call itself when done, just bumping one parameter to turn a recursion into an iteration.

Let's say you want to ping N urls in order (perhaps a poor example, but still valid).

```
function pingURL(index) {
    if(index>=urlArray.length) {
        return 'Done';
    } else {
        theURL=urlArray[index];
        jQuery.ajax({
                    url:...
                    data: {urltoPing:theUrl}
                   }).done(function(response) {
                       otherFunctions(response);
                       index=index+1;
                       pingUrl(index);
                   });

    }
}

pingURL(0);
```